# Windows Scripting Commands Not Recognized

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ksh, windows-scripting

I am trying to run a cmd file but I am receiving strange errors. I am running this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#@echo off
#REM *************************************************************************
...
...
```

But the results are returned with errors like so:

```
C:>#!/bin/ksh
'#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>#@echo off
'#@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:>#REM *************************************************************************
'#REM' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried this on two computers with the same results. Can any one tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `ksh` script, launch it though `ksh` (or any shell like `bash`, `sh`, `csh` or `tcsh` which understand the `#!` line) and not the windows command line. You may need to install `cygwin` (with `ksh`), start a cygwin terminal and launch your script from there.